# Strange Bash Variable Assignment Behaviour in For Loop

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, for-loop

I'm assigning a variable inside a for loop where I make an output file name from the provided input.

I've never had any problems with arrays or for loops before but the behaviour is very strange. I've used similar for loops elsewhere in the code which all work fine. The code below works fine and the variable is assigned as expected.

```
count=1

for i in "${INPUT[@]}"
do
    local INPUT[$count]=`echo -n "$i" | sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g'`

    let count=count+1
done
```

That all works as expected, however, the code below does not work.

```
count=1

for i in "${INPUT[@]}"
do
    local OUTFILE[$count]="$i"

    let count=count+1
done
```

If I echo out the value of $INPUT[$count] or $i I get my expected result, however, when I echo out the value of $OUTFILE[$count] after assignment, it comes out as [1], [2], [3], etc. rather than person's name, person's name, person's name, etc.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `local` keyword here?

Comment: It's inside a function

Comment: I haven't seen this usage before. Does it turnthe whole array into a local variable? Or just this entry? Is there a reference for this syntax?

Comment: Does taking it out help?

Comment: It was misplaced curly braces when references which was the problem. The code referenced is part of a larger script with several functions.

The reason I copy input into outfile is because input under goes further manipulation and may involve newlines or other escape characters which is why I make a copy of it before manipulating it.

Comment: Unrelated tip: since the array index is evaluated in an arithmetic context, you can increment `count` "inline" with `local OUTFILE[count++]="$i"`.

Comment: The whole array is local I believe. I didn't see anything explicit about this in the man page though. `declare` mentions that it accepts `name[sub]=value` and ignores `sub` but that's the closest I saw (and not directly relevant because this assignment certainly doesn't ignore the index.

Comment: @EtanReisner: For the record, in bash, `declare`, `typeset` and `local` are all effectively the same command. The only difference with `local` is that it throws an error if you use it outside of a function. They all accept the forms `<cmd> array[idx]=value` and `<cmd> -A array[key]=value`, which declare `array` to be an array (or associative array), and then set the value of a single element. The fact that `local` is the same as `declare` means that `local -g` declares a variable to be global. I don't recommend that usage, however.

Comment: @rici Indeed. The fact that the man page separates them the way it does is confusing and complicated for no real reason that I can tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are writing something like

```
echo $OUTFILE[$count]
```

when you should be writing

```
echo ${OUTFILE[$count]}
```

Comment: Yes, that was it, I feel rather silly now. It was part of a larger string concatenation as part of a full file path and I had the curly braces misplaced. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To copy an array into another BASH array you don't need a loop, you can just do:

```
OUTFILE=( "${INPUT[@]}" )
```

Comment: Thank you! This wasn't the cause of the problem but it's a good thing to know so thank you!

Although, I'm curious about this because I haven't seen it in documentation and Vim is highlighting the right outer bracket in red to suggest invalid syntax.

Comment: @Kervate There's nothing about this that needs explicit calling out in the documentation as such. It is just normal array construction where the values are being taken from the expansion of all elements of another array. vim shouldn't be mis-highlighting that though (well possibly if not in bash mode I suppose but I think that would be a mistake also).

Comment: Yes vim highlighting have many modes and better to select BASH mode to get correct syntax highlighting.

Comment: Pretty sure it is in Bash mode because I've used a fair few Bashisms such as "local" and "function" and it syntax highlights all of that fine